# Two definitions about reflexive polytopes

Tags: volume, polytopes, discrete-geometry

I am working through [Computing the Continuous Discretely](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/noprint.pdf) and they give the definition of a reflexive polytope as $$ P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : Ax \leq 1\}$$ where all entries from $A$ are integers.

It's left as an exercise to the reader to show, that
$$ P^{\mathrm{o}} \cap \mathbb{Z}^d = \{0\} \text{ and } (t+1)P^{\mathrm{o}} \cap \mathbb{Z}^d=tP \cap \mathbb{Z}^d$$ where t is a natural number, follows from the given definition.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $P^{\circ}$ being the polar set of $P$ ? ...That you should maybe redefine for the benefit of completeness. Besides is $t$ **any** integer ?

Comment: P^{\mathrm{o}} being the interior of the polytop P. And t is any positive integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that you should include in your text. Besides, a last precision : do you mean $((t+1)P)^{\mathrm{o}}$ or $(t+1)(P^{\mathrm{o}})$ ?

Comment: I think both would be the same

Comment: Hint: can you show that $P \subset [-1,1]^d$?

Comment: Could only do that for $d=1$ (which is trivial :), could you maybe add one more hint?

Answer (score 0):

Obeserve that $P$ is full-dimensional (otherwise it would not make sense to talk about the interior of $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$) as it contains a small ball around the origin.

Since $A$ is integral, we have $Az\leq 0$ for $z\in P^{\mathrm{o}}\cap\mathbb{Z}^d$. Note that $C=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^d : Ax\leq 0\rbrace$ defines a polyhedral cone. The boundedness of $P$ combined with $C\subseteq P$ implies that the cone is bounded itself. This can only be the case if $C=\lbrace 0\rbrace$. Thus, $z = 0$.

For the second claim, we observe that $(t+1)P^{\mathrm{o}} = \lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}^d : Ax < (t+1)1\rbrace$. Again, we have $Az\leq t1$ for $z\in (t+1)P^{\mathrm{o}}\cap \mathbb{Z}^d$ which shows $z\in tP\cap\mathbb{Z}^d$. The reverse inclusion follows from $tP\subseteq (t+1)P^{\mathrm{o}}$.